# What is this chip-like icon in device manager?

Tags: device-manager

This is how it looks:

[image: screenshot of icon in device manager]

What is this icon?

Comment: It's just part of the icon. I have it on my desktop too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s an add-in card, ie. a PCI Express or PCI card. It’s combined with an additional icon to signal the type of add-in card:

- Display – hence the monitor
- Disk HBA – hence the disk

On “Storage controllers”, you can see a slightly larger version:

[image]

The secondary icon here is the “Single Ended Parallel SCSI icon”.

Higher-resolution version of the icons are present in `setupapi.dll`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the back of the chip you can see it's a hard drive, they put a chip on top of it to show that it's the controller of the hard drive and not the hard drive itself.